# Refresh token is null after authenticating user account

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth

I am authenticating user account and writing the details in a json file to connect to cloud. How to get refresh token

Below is my code which does the authentication and storing details in json

```
try:
    with open(file, 'r') as infile:
        creds = json.load(infile)
except FileNotFoundError:
    return ''
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    return ''

credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    'access_token',
    refresh_token=creds['refresh_token'],
    token_uri=creds['token_uri'],
    client_id=creds['client_id'],
    client_secret=creds['client_secret'],
    scopes=creds['scopes'])

refresh_token = creds['refresh_token']
print(refresh_token)
return credentials
```

I am getting null for the refresh token

```
{"refresh_token": null,
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"client_id": "13465789222- 
tmd611m4j6ofdpsvp25t59s2gf6im4ed.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"client_secret": "HCdEIght0997j5iL2ewi2vUnM-", 
"scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]}
```

Comment: did you provide offline_access in scope?

Comment: Hi Sagar, I am very new to this cloud related things. I am not sure what is scope offline access

Comment: You can't the refresh token until you have scope of offline_access.

Comment: Use this scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "offline_access"]

Comment: How can we have offline access, can you please provide me more details if you have please

Comment: sure will use that

Comment: appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            client_secrets_file,
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' ,"offline_access"]) Its giving invalid scope when I run the script

Comment: We can have meeting in video call if you want.